# Simple template in Python (no templating engines please)

Tags: python, string, templates, escaping, templating

This code

```
txt = "f'{string} a great day'"
with open('new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    out.write(f'{string} a great day')
```

write "have a great day" into new.txt file.

This code

```
txt = "f'{string} a great day'"
with open('new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    out.write(txt)
```

doesn't. It writes literal
`f'{string} a great day'`
in the new.txt file.

Why?

Is there a way to make the second chunk of code do what the first chunk of code does?

Comment: There's a difference between an expression and a string containing an expression. As there is a difference between a car and photo of a car.

Comment: even worse: it's like I have a head, and I have a head which is contemplating the head itself :) - looks like they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code is a string that contains `f''` and python will not react/format value. but there is a solution for what you want, you must use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function.

```
txt = "f'{string} a great day'"
with open('new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    out.write(eval(txt))
```